# How exactly works this Hibernate Many To Many relation implementation? Is it my reasoning correct?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, rdbms

I am pretty new in Hibernate and I have some doubt related this tutorial example that implement a **ManyToMany** use case.

So I have these 2 entity classes:

1) **Movie**:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
                    name="movie_actor",
                    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")},
                    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="actor_id")}
        )

    private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<Actor>();   

    public Movie() {}
    public Movie(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

}
```

2) **Actor**:

```
@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="actors")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>();

    public Actor() {}   
    public Actor(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }
}
```

So it mean that a **Movie** instance can be associated to many actors (many actors act into a single movie) and at the same time an **Actor** instance can be associated to many movie (a single actor can act in many movie).

So the **Movie** class is the **owner of the many to many relation** because it contains:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
                name="movie_actor",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="actor_id")}
    )

private Set<Actor> actors = new HashSet<Actor>();
```

and the **Actor** class is the **inverse end of the relation**.

It means that, into the database, will be created a **movie_actor** association table that use the id of the **Movie** table and **Actor** table to create the relaion.

And it means that an **Actor** instance is not responsible about the update so if I add a new actor and I set a movie to it, the actor will be inserted into the **Actor** table but the relation is not insert into the **movie_actor** association table.

To do it I have to create a new **Movie** object, then set the actors on it and persist this **Movie** object, so in this way will be performed the Movie object on the Movie table, the related Actor objects on the Actor table and the related record into the **movie_actor** association table.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Tnx

Comment: Why don't you try it and query the database to see what happens when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"So the Movie class is the owner of the many to many relation because it contains..."*

No, the `Movie` is the owner because the `Actor` contains [`mappedBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#mappedBy%28%29):

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship
>   is unidirectional.

*"To do it I have to create a new Movie object, then set the actors on it and persist this Movie object..."*

Yes, but it doesn't have to be a new `Movie`, it can be an existing one to which you can add existing or new `Actor` instances.

Regarding everything else, the answer is: Yes, your reasoning is correct.